# How can I force CFHTTP not to encode a query parameter?

Tags: java, coldfusion, jvm, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

I have been using ColdFusion 10 with JVM 1.6 to communicate with an AS400 API to fetch data for a client's web site. I send a URL query parameter that includes commas. This worked fine for years.

Recently, I updated to ColdFusion 11, with JVM 1.8. Now, the API calls fail, because the CFHTTP tag is URL-encoding the query parameter value. The APi no longer sees the commas, or understands that it needs to decode the parameter string.

Is there any way to force the CFHTTP tag to avoid encoding the query parameter? I have tried putting the query in the host string as well as separately in a CFHTTPParam tag.

Also, is this likely to have occurred because I upgraded to ColdFusion 11, or because I upgraded the JVM to 1.8?

Comment: Are you using `<cfhttpparam encoded="no" ...>`?

Comment: yes, i have tried that but it had no effect. if I read the docs correctly, this is ignored for get requests anyway

Comment: (Edit) Yeah, without seeing the code, I wasn't sure if you were using get or post. Never mind, forgot get requests don't usually allow type=body.

Answer (score 3):

The CF2016 updates need to be applied.  I just ran into this issue myself and update 6 solves this.  I recommend applying each update up to version 10.

Comment: Did they fix the issue for CF11 too?

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting the solution.